# Chess health benefits

Tags: psychology

I recently read an interesting article, and was surprised to see that there are actually mental health benefits to playing chess. How often does this happen, and in what instances?

Comment: Why not give a link or at least reference to the article? Otherwise, you are asking others to comment on second-hand detail-free information. Without seeing the article itself, my [replication crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis) detector is sounding an alarm. There have been hundreds of published studies of the form "______ is correlated with healthy _____" (fill in the blanks) and such studies have been notoriously hard to replicate.